# Insert column from *.txt file to end of existing MySQL table

Tags: mysql, database, insert, mysql-workbench

I am trying to load the contents of a *.txt file to the end of a MySQL database table.i.e. I want to append the contents of the file to an existing table in MySQL. I am working in MySQL Workbench (Windows 7). I downloaded the Windows 5.6.21 installer from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/:

Here is the MySQL code that I am working with:

#### Create database, table and load file:

```
CREATE SCHEMA fileimport2;
USE fileimport2;
CREATE TABLE testtable(column1 INT, column2 VARCHAR(255), column3 DECIMAL(8,4));
LOAD DATA INFILE 'File.txt'
INTO TABLE foo COLUMNS TERMINATED BY '\t';
```

At this point, the database has one table with 3 rows and 3 columns. NOTE: I have tried:

```
SET GLOBAL local_infile = 'ON';
```

but I still cannot get

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'File2.txt'
```

to work. For this reason, I am instead using:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'File2.txt'
```

#### Next, I add a 4th column at the end of the table:

```
ALTER TABLE testtable
ADD column4 VARCHAR(255)
AFTER column3;
```

At this point, the 4th column is created.

Now, I want try to load the file named 'File2.txt' into rows 1,2,3 of column # 4:

#### Put values into column # 4, from a *.txt file that has one column:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'File2.txt'
INTO TABLE testtable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(@col1,@col2,@col3,@col4) set column4=@col4;
```

#### View table:

```
SELECT * FROM testtable
```

Problem:
When I do this, the contents of the file 'File2.txt' are added to rows 4,5,6 of column # 4. Rows 1,2,3 of column 4 are NULL. Rows 4,5,6 of columns 1,2,3 are NULL. This is not what I wanted. I do not want the null entries. My final table should be 3 rows X 4 columns.

Image showing problem:
[image: Result showing problem]

#### File Contents:

File.txt (the columns are separated by tabs):

```
1 First line of text 7.24
2 Second line goes here 5.7
3 Sample text on line 3 11.6
```

File2.txt:

```
before today
one tow
ssf three
```

Question:
Is there a way to load the file (like a horizontal concatenation) into rows 1,2,3 of column #4?

Comment: I have added an image to the original post showing the problem. I have posted my attempt at this and done a lot of searching online. Your help would be really appreciated since I am stuck with this at the moment.

Comment: Hi everyone, any feedback you can offer about this would be great. Thanks in advance.